# Removing mistaken tag synonym

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

Quick housekeeping question.

I have created two tag synonyms back to front (ie wrong master tag). Can I delete these or do we wait until they are downvoted and disappear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mods can deal with them, so when it happens, alerting us to the actual mistake allows us to fix. That may be via a swap or by deleting the synonym so that a revote can happen.